# Report Builder - Connection String - Work 1 place but not the other

Tags: reporting-services, connection-string, reportbuilder

Datasource "Test Connection" works when building connection string. But not when using that same connection string to connect to datasource!

Using Report Builder to create connection to datasource, I use the Build button.

Under Build Popup, I type in:

- Name
- Connection Type
- Credentials
  Pressing "Test Connection" and I get "Test connection Succeded".

When using the connection string I get from Build function, adding the credentials, and pressing "Test Connection" I get API.ERROR FAILED.

Result is I'm not able to retrieve data.

How come Data Source Connection works in the "Build" popup and not when using the string it generates?

[Connection Succeded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87MxD.png)

[Connection Failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWEzT.png)

Answer (score 1):

This issue can happen when you are connected to a Report Server. Report Builder is a 32-bit application whereas the Report Server uses 64-bit connections. So the test that succeeds is running it locally, but the one that fails is trying to run it through the Report Server.

The solution is to click the `disconnect` link at the bottom of Report Builder before editing the connection. Then both tests should pass. After you upload the report to the server, you can change the `Data Source` there to use the 64-bit version that works there. Unfortunately, if this is the case, you'll have to go through these changes every time you edit the report.

The issue could also be something similar like the drivers are installed locally but not on the server etc.